# JQuery OnClick not changing text on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Have a basic link that I am using as a button and changing the text when the user clicks it to go from edit to done editing. When I first click the button, the click event happens but the text does not change until I click it again which is throwing off and not behaving as I would like:

HTML:

```
 <a type="button" id="editButton" class="editButton" style="cursor: pointer">EDIT</a>
```

JS:

```
$("#editButton").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('editButt');
    if ($this.hasClass('editButt')) {
        $this.text('EDIT');
    } else {
        $this.text('DONE EDITING');
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/icweat/U8Ns3/3/)

Comment: Its working see http://jsfiddle.net/U8Ns3/5/ what make you think its not working

Comment: I see what you're saying. That certainly makes it react quicker. Now I need to add the class. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You toggle a class that is not present at first click, so it mean it will add it and then run your condition.

Add the class and problem solved

```
<a type="button" id="editButton" class="editButton editButt" style="cursor: pointer">EDIT</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U8Ns3/4/

Comment: That's it Karl-André Gagnon - Thank you. Will mark as the answer when I can in 8 mins.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, and see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwisch45/wkxJN/)

```
$("#editButton").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('editButt')) {
        $this.text('EDIT');
    } else {
        $this.text('DONE EDITING');
    }
    $this.toggleClass('editButt');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler solution, here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/c9Qsx/)**</kbd>

```
<button type="button" id="editButton" class="edit">EDIT</button>


$('#editButton').click(function() {
  var text = ($(this).text() === 'EDIT') ? 'DONE EDITING' : 'EDIT';
  $(this).text(text).toggleClass('done');
});
```